# Can I impose some a priori constraints on a distribution found by SmoothKernelDistribution?

Tags: numerics, probability-or-statistics, fitting, distributions, estimation

I use [`SmoothKernelDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothKernelDistribution.html) (with no options and a single argument — a list of values) to get an approximate reconstruction of a continuous distribution based on a finite sample of values. It is known *a priori* that the actual distribution is unimodal and its PDF is exactly 0 for x ≤ 0.

Can I provide some options to `SmoothKernelDistribution` so that it tries to find an approximate distribution within these constraints?

On the plot below horizontal positions of the vertical gray lines represent the sample values, the blue curve is an approximate distribution returned by `SmoothKernelDistribution`, and the orange curve conveys a general idea how the actual distribution may look like; its exact shape, kurtosis, height and position of the peak may vary significantly, so I cannot just fit some known parameterized distribution to the sample using `EstimatedDistribution`.

[image: distribution plot]

Comment: maybe soemthing like `dist = SmoothKernelDistribution[data, Automatic, {"Bounded", {0, 1},   "Gaussian"}]`?

Comment: A sample of your data would help.

Comment: "Data don't lie" and "In theory there is no difference between theory and practice. In practice there is."  It sure looks like the distribution has two bumps despite knowing *a priori* that it shouldn't.

Comment: A more constructive comment:  To force the pdf to be 0 at 0 there is the *negative reflection technique* in the following paper:  https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March02/Silverman/paper.pdf (Equation 2.16, next to last page).  I'll see if I can cook up an example.

Answer (score 8):

The `"Bounded"` option of `SmoothKernelDistribution` (which uses a reflection of the data technique) usually ends up with a non-zero value for the pdf at zero (which is many times exactly what you want).  But when you need the pdf of zero to be zero a "negative reflection technique" is one possible approach.  ([Silverman, 1986](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March02/Silverman/paper.pdf))

Fortunately, it's easily programmed.  Using @BobHanlon 's example:

```
SeedRandom[1234]
data = RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[1, 1], 1000];

(* Using original data *)
skdPlus = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];
(* Using the reflected data *)
skdMinus = SmoothKernelDistribution[-data];

Plot[{PDF[LogNormalDistribution[1, 1], x],
  PDF[skdPlus, x] - PDF[skdMinus, x]}, {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"True", "Estimated"}]
```

[image: True and estimated pdf]

**Addition:**

When there is a pronounced peak, then using an "Adaptive" bandwidth technique can work out better.  (This is where the bandwidth used is narrower where the data is denser and wider out in the tails.)

```
SeedRandom[1234]
data = RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[1, 1], 10000];

(* Using original data *)
skdPlus = SmoothKernelDistribution[data, {"Adaptive", 1, Automatic}];
(* Using the reflected data *)
skdMinus = SmoothKernelDistribution[-data, {"Adaptive", 1, Automatic}];

Plot[{PDF[LogNormalDistribution[1, 1], x],
  PDF[skdPlus, x] - PDF[skdMinus, x]}, {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"True", "Estimated"}]
```

[image: True and estimated using adaptive bandwidth]

Now, I've purposely chosen 1 as the bandwidth to make it look good.  (Shame on me.)  Here's what you get with `"Automatic"`:

[image: True and estimated with adaptive and automatically chosen bandwidth]

Answer (score 4):

```
SeedRandom[1234]

data = RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[1, 1], 1000];
```

From the documentation, "The kernel function ker can be specified to account for known bounding on the underlying density using {"Bounded", c, ker}, where c can be any real number, a list {Subscript[c, 1],Subscript[c, 2]} such that Subscript[c, 1] < Subscript[c, 2], or a list {{Subscript[c, 11], Subscript[c, 12]}, {Subscript[c, 21], Subscript[c, 22]},…}, with length equal to the dimension of data."

```
Show[
 Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"],
 Plot[
  PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[data, 
    Automatic, {"Bounded", {0, 20}, "Gaussian"}], x],
  {x, -1, 20}, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}}],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, All}]
```

[image]